# Prompt window to choose download location not working for chrome on arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chrome

I recently reinstalled my chrome browser and also cleared up the application's cache and config folders.

Ever since I made a fresh install, I have been unable to download files when I have the `"Ask where to save each file before downloading"` option turned on under chrome's `Settings -> Advanced -> Downloads`. I am able to download files to the directory I have predefined in my settings when I have this option turned off.

I use a window manager, DWM with arch Linux and have gtk3 and gtk4 already installed. The download location prompt window works for firefox but not chrome.

What can I do to make the prompt window show up again for me on chrome to choose my download location?

[SOLUTION]:

When I open chrome, I keep receiving this prompt to set chrome as my default browser. I kept receiving this even though click on the "set as default" button.

Opening chrome from the terminal as asked for in the comments showed me the message `xdg-settings: $BROWSER is set and can't be changed with xdg-settings`.

I ran a `killall chrome` command and `unset BROWSER` on the terminal and used the same terminal to run chrome again. This time clicking on the "set as default" button worked.

After doing this, the window to choose download location started working.

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland?

Comment: I use X11 and don't have Wayland installed

Comment: Can you try to execute from terminal CLI and see if at the moment of clicking the option you can see any errors? chrome is a static executable, but my work to check "log" errors.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed. I have edited the solution into the post.

Comment: Please explain how to "Open chrome from the terminal."  I'm using Windows 10. I tried Start > cmd > killall chrome, but Windows responds, "killall is not a recognized command."